# Phonegap App Works in iOS 6 but not iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios5, cordova, jquery-mobile, requirejs

All that happens in iOS 5 is the 'DeviceReady' and 'Load' events being fired and all of my files are being loaded

My stack includes:

```
Cordova 2.2.0rc2
Phonegap ChildBrowser
Phonegap InAppPurchaseManager
BackboneJS
UnderscoreJS
jQuery 1.8.1
jQueryMobile 1.2.0
RequireJS
ParseJS
```

I can see that the files have loaded because I have the corresponding JS objects:

```
CDV
window.plugins.childBrowser
window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager
Backbone
_
$
$.mobile
require
Parse
```

However, the step that isn't happening is RequireJS loading the `main.js` file. And why this doesn't happen for iOS 5 when it happens for iOS 6 is extremely confusing.

Any ideas on why this may be happening? I'm very open to trying things.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) to debug the application remotely. [This blog post at phonegap.com](http://phonegap.com/2011/05/18/debugging-phonegap-javascript/) explains how you can use Weinre to debug your application. It should display any JavaScript errors that your app might produce.

Comment: I don't get any JavaScript errors. On iOS 6, I get logs from my app.js file (loaded form main.js, which is loaded form require.js). However, on iOS 5, I don't get any logs from app.js - my app doesn't start.

Comment: Which version of iOS 5 are you using? ChildBrowser is known to cause problems with iOS 5.0 version.

Comment: I tried both iOS 5 and 5.1. Removing ChildBrowser didn't fix it :( This makes sense, because using weinre I found the window.plugins.childBrowser variable defined properly.